# initializeApp in google cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to write a google cloud function to return a custom token, given a uid.

I am getting an error:

> login rp645l30gf7u FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).

I have initialised the app, see the code below. I have also tried to initialise using firebase-admin - see the commented out code.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// const admin = require("firebase-admin");
// admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
initializeApp();
const {getAuth} = require("firebase/auth");

// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

exports.login = functions
    .region("europe-west2")
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
      

      getAuth().createCustomToken(request.query.uid).then((customToken) => {
        response.status(200).send("hi");
        // response.status(200).send(customToken);
      }).catch((error) => {
        response.status(406).send(error);
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Are you in the correct project?

Comment: Yes but this prompted me to take a look a d think my functions region and firebase region are different.

Comment: It wasn't an issue with location

Comment: `firebase` and `firebase-admin` are two independent libraries. If you are calling `initializeApp()` from `firebase-admin/app`, you need to be bringing in `getAuth()` from `firebase-admin/auth` to match.

Comment: Thank you, I have sorted it by changing this